# c++ generic way to check a value in a range

Tags: c++, templates

In maths there are different kind of range: they can be open ( (a, b) ), close ( [a, b] ), left opened (a, b] ) or right opened ( [a, b) ).

I want write a template function in C++ (not 11) that can easly manage these situation. But I'm not much confident with meta-programming and templates.

I want to have something this:

```
const int max = MAX, int min = MIN;
int x = value;
// check close range
if ( is_in_range( x, min, max ) ) //...

if ( is_in_range( x, min, max, open) ) //...
if ( is_in_range( x, min, max, left_open) ) //...
if ( is_in_range( x, min, max, right_open) ) //...
```

Does somebody have some suggest?

**EDIT 1**

I've tryed this but cannot compile

```
enum { range_open, range_close, range_left_open, range_right_open };

namespace detail {

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_open_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min < x ) && ( x < max );
    }

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_close_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min <= x ) && ( x <= max );
    }

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_left_open_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min < x ) && ( x <= max );
    }

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_right_open_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min <= x ) && ( x < max );
    }

 }

template < typename Type, int range_open >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min );

template < typename Type, range_open >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
{
    return detail::check_open_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type, range_close >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
{
    return detail::check_close_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type, check_left_open_range >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
{
    return detail::check_left_open_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type, check_right_open_range >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
{
    return detail::check_right_open_range( x, min, max );
}
```

but effectly is more simple do it with 4 overloaded functions

**Edit 2**

```
namespace detail {

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_open_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min < x ) && ( x < max );
    }

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_close_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min <= x ) && ( x <= max );
    }

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_left_open_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min < x ) && ( x <= max );
    }

    template < typename Type >
    inline bool check_right_open_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min )
    {
        return ( min <= x ) && ( x < max );
    }
}

struct range_open {};
struct range_close {};
struct left_open_range {};
struct right_open_range {};

template < typename Type >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min)
{
    return detail::check_open_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min, const range_open&)
{
    return detail::check_open_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min, const range_close& )
{
    return detail::check_close_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min, const left_open_range& )
{
    return detail::check_left_open_range( x, min, max );
}

template < typename Type >
inline bool check_range( const Type& x, const Type& max, const Type& min, const right_open_range& )
{
    return detail::check_right_open_range( x, min, max );
}
```

I think that Edit 2 is right...

**Edit 3: Good version**

struct left_open {
        template 
        static bool compare (const T& value, const T& range) { return range < value; }
    };

```
struct left_close {
    template <class T>
    static bool compare (const T& value, const T& range) { return range <= value; }
};

struct right_open  {
    template <class T>
    static bool compare (const T& value, const T& range) { return value < range; }
};

struct right_close {
    template <class T>
    static bool compare (const T& value, const T& range) { return value <= range; }
}; 

template <class L, class R, class T>
bool check_range(const T& value, const T& min, const T& max)
{
    return L::compare <T> (value, min) && R::compare <T> (value, max);
}
```

Comment: Do you need metaprogramming for this?

Comment: It looks like you want to decide the "openness" (closed/open/left_open/right_open) of the range during runtime. Is this intentional, or could you just as well decide that when writing the code?

Comment: In template metaprogramming, `<>` are typically used in place of `()` (and then the resulting value must be retrieved manually)

Comment: Is there meanwhile something available in the STL for checking ranges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here something that works on VS2010:-

```
class LeftOpen 
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static bool Compare (const T value, const T range) { return value >= range; }
};

class LeftClosed
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static bool Compare (const T value, const T range) { return value > range; }
};

class RightOpen 
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static bool Compare (const T value, const T range) { return value <= range; }
};

class RightClosed
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static bool Compare (const T value, const T range) { return value < range; }
};

template <class L, class R, class T>
bool IsInRange (T value, T min, T max) { return L::Compare <T> (value, min) && R::Compare <T> (value, max); }

int main()
{
  int
    min = 5,
    max = 99;

  bool
    r1 = IsInRange <LeftOpen, RightOpen> (-19, min, max),
    r2 = IsInRange <LeftOpen, RightOpen> (45, min, max),
    r3 = IsInRange <LeftOpen, RightOpen> (149, min, max);
}
```

Comment: Ok... I was searching exactly that... but is it Standard C++ ? Can it compile with g++ or clang?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: Should work, it's not being very 'clever' with anything. The only issue might be the deduction of the third template parameter to IsInRange, which you could add explicitly.

Comment: @Skizz, gcc complains of explicit invocation L::Compare <T>. Just removing <T> works. not sure why

Comment: Is it good replace const T value with const T& value and T value with const T& value?

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution is to use overloads:

```
namespace range_policy
{
  struct open {};
  struct left_open {};
  struct right_open {};
  ...
};

template <typename T>
bool is_in_range(const T& a, const T& min, const T& max, range_policy::open) { .... }

template <typename T>
bool is_in_range(const T& a, const T& min, const T& max, range_policy::left_open) { .... }
```

where each `is_in_range` overload is implemented accordingly.

In C++11 you could consider using a strongly typed enum instead of the dummy `structs`:

```
enum class range_policy {open, left_open, right_open, ....};
```

Comment: it seems he wants to have the range functions generic across all types, not just int.

Comment: @Chethan fine, that is just a detail. Edited.

Comment: Yes it must works with any type that as defined < and <= operator

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the tag dispatching technique of template programming.  Your is_in_range function would have 4 overloads, each of which is distinguished by a parameter (unused in the function) to select the right overload.  Each overload could simply increment/decrement the min/max to achieve the range you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Make an enumeration for this.

```
enum RangeType
{
   close,
   open,
   left_open,
   right_open
}

bool is_in_range(int x, int min, int max, RangeType type) { }
```

Comment: it seems he wants to have the range functions generic across all types, not just int.