# using typedef with template

Tags: c++, templates

The code below [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339380/c-generic-way-to-check-a-value-in-a-range) (and modified a bit) produce the following error message using g++ compiler:
error: template declaration of 'typedef'
/RangeChecks.hpp:145:12: error: 'IsInRange' does not name a type

here are the relevant parts from my RangeChecks.hpp file:

```
class GreaterEqual
{
  public:
     template <class T>
     static bool Compare (const T& value, const T& threshold)
     {
        return !(value < threshold); /* value >= threshold */
     }
};

class LessEqual
{
  public:
     template <class T>
     static bool Compare (const T& value, const T& threshold)
     {
        return !(value > threshold); /* value <= threshold */
     }
};

template <class L, class R, class T>
bool IsInRange (const T& value, const T& min, const T& max)
{
     return L::template Compare<T> (value, min) && R::template Compare<T> (value, max);
}

typedef IsInRange< GreaterEqual , LessEqual > isInClosedRange;
```

I searched over the internet for an answer and there are simular things but non of them, that i found, solved my problem.

Comment: @myaut those kind of alias declarations are still only for types, and this is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsInRange` is a function, not a type. The easiest way to do what you want to do is to write a wrapper:

```
template<class T>
bool isInClosedRange(const T& value, const T& min, const T& max) {
    return IsInRange<T, GreaterEqual, LessEqual>(value, min, max);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`IsInRange` is a function template, not a class template, so an instantiation of it is not a type, so you can't create a typedef for it.

Comment: is it possible to define IsInRange as a class template? would it make sense to do it?